# Valid to use future after corresponding promise leaves scope

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous

If you extract a `future` from a `promise`, is it valid to call `future::get_value` after the `promise` leaves scope?

```
std::future<void> future;
{
    std::promise<void> promise;
    future = promise.get_future();
    promise.set_value();
}
future.wait();
```

I am unable to find an answer using [promise](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise)'s and [future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future)'s documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Promises and future have a shared state.

A future whose promise was not fullfilled and was destroyed is a broken promise.  The shared state is given an exception and made ready.

But a future whose promise was fullfilled and then the promise was destroyed is perfectly ok.  The shared state persists.

Look at [`~promise`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/~promise) and the discussion about shared state on the [main doc page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise).

Comment: Thank you, that is clear. From this I conclude that my example is correct?

Comment: @AartStuurman I didn't audit the code; I just found the answer to the question.  I don't see anything obviously wrong with it.  It is strange to ready *all* promises at once, but there is so much commented out what can I say...  Myself, when I have a job queue that can abort, I use an `optional` or `expected` in the future (I prefer this to exceptions; let the client throw if they cannot recover from an abandoned job).  Also, in a real job queue, I'd expect threads, and hence condition variables.  Again, all stuff that could be omitted, but determining correctness of threading is hard.

Comment: Hmm maybe I made my example too complicated. It is not part of an actual code base and functions only as example for using a removed promise. I'll see if I can simplify for the sake of having a clear question. Thank you anyway for the effort of looking into the code.